# How will I get the point of intersection?

Tags: analytic-geometry, circles

I'm confuse on how will I get the point of intersection of these two equations:
**$x^2+y^2+5x+y-26=0$ and $x^2+y^2+2x-y-15=0$**

I tried using the elimination method but I can't get it.

Comment: Subtract one equation from the other to get a linear equation, solve that equation for one variable in terms of the other, substitute back into one of the original equations.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Subtract both the equations. You get a linear equation as follows:

$$3x+2y-11=0$$
$$y=\frac{11-3x}{2}$$
Now substitute $y$ in terms of $x$ in any of the given equations.

Answer (score 0):

You have the equations of two circles.

If you subtract one from the other you get something like $3x+2y-11=0$ which is the line between the two points of intersection.  Make $y$ (or $x$) the subject of this equation, substitute into one of the circle equations, solve the quadratic and continue as usual to answer the question.